# How to make custom WordPress theme show pages, NOT posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have recently created a custom WordPress theme, following a guide I found online.

However, all of the guides I came across explain how to set up a blogging site and do not explain how to set up a static website page. I am guessing that it is something to do with this code in my index.php:

> .

```
                >.   get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            >.   endwhile; endif; 
        >.   ?>
```

When I remove this, it removes the blog layout. However, I do not know what to amend to make a static page layout.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You need to specify the static page using settings otherwise if you don't your blog page will appear as the first page of your site

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have done this already in WordPress and it does show my home page, but in a post format (I.e. It uses excerpts as though it were a blog. I figured something in that code is telling all pages to be displayed as blogs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_post_format()` Returns the **post** format of a **post**. This will usually be called in the the loop, but can be used anywhere if a post ID is provided. and its usually found on the posts pages/blogs.. therefore Its used in a theme when you want to display blog posts.

As you you might know that wp have different posts types. let's just take two of them.

`Post (Post Type: 'post')`

`Page (Post Type: 'page')`

The `get_post_format()` is used to get the format of a post,(blog Post) if you open your wp dashboard and start a new post or editing existing post you will see different posts formats types

[image]

As you can see from the image above, the red highlited part is the post format, that is what you are requesting when u use `get_post_format()` wp treats that template as it should display posts, but not pages.

If you want the content of the page you then need to use `the_content()`

Therefore this

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

endwhile; endif;
```

becomes :

```
get_template_part( 'content', the_content() );

endwhile; endif;
```

alternatively :

```
 <div class="YourContainer">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="YourContentDiv">

   <?php the_content();?>

  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else:
        echo "no content found";
   ?>
<?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps, Goodluck

Comment: Thank you so much - this was really helpful!

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the page template hierarchy you will see which template is used in which circumstances:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

For example if you create a front-page.php template it will take precedence of other templates.

If you set a static home page in settings then the template used will depend on the hierarchy first a custom named selectable template if this isn't set then a page-$slug.php template e.g. home-page.php then if that doesn't exist then a page-$id.php e.g 15-page.php if this doesn't exist then page.php will be used then singular.php then index.php